# IBM BPM 7.5 Log Files on Unix

Tags: unix, websphere, business-process-management

I have Websphere Application Server running on Unix. I have no problem developing and administering Websphere and IBM BPM tools since 6.x but I'm new to Unix OS. Is there any tool that allows me to see the SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log, etc. other than in Unix directly or in the WAS admin console? On a Windows editor for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a BPM question, more of a Websphere admin question.  When I've wanted to view the WAS files in a more user friendly environment than a *nix command line, I generally get SFTP access (If you have ssh access you likely already have this) and then using a text editor that supports loading files over an SFTP Connection.

I'm not a windows person.  On the Mac I've used various packages for this.  A quick search shows one recommended option is [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/).  I've also used [Jedit](http://www.jedit.org/) for this in the past.

You might also be able to get a widows helper to allow you to mount SFTP sites as a drive on your windows box and then use whatever Windows Text Editor you prefer I've done this using [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) which appears to have a windows version as well as the Mac version I run.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` and `System.err` can be viewed in WAS console. Go to `Troubleshooting / Logs and trace / <server> / JVM Logs / Runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux machine then you can use the following command for tracking your log
For example my logs are present in /opt/IBM/v8.5/profiles/PCNode1/logs/server1/
so here is how we can track it,

> tail
>   usage: tail -100f /opt/IBM/v8.5/profiles/PCNode1/logs/server1/SystemOut.log or SysemErr.log

Even you can use the 'vi' eiditor to look at your

> vi /opt/IBM/v8.5/profiles/PCNode1/logs/server1/SystemOut.log or SysemErr.log

Hope this is helpful